How to know subtree's knot sum?
I have table tree
create table Tree(
id Int primary key,
pid Int REFERENCES Tree(id), 
weight Int)

I have data like this



id
pid
weight




4
null
3


1
4
1


5
4
1


6
4
1


2
1
1


3
1
1


7
3
2


8
3
1




I want to calculate weight of all subtree to have data like this



id
pid
sum




4
null
14


1
4
9


5
4
1


6
4
1


2
1
1


3
1
4


7
3
1


8
3
1



How to create query to have such result? Thanks for assistance, I've been struggling with this problem for 4 days

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

You need a recursive cte for this. But I don't see how your sample data can produce the output you are looking for. The sum of the weight for every row in your sample data is only 11.

Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

This is a simple recursive cte, although, the data, expected and image data don't quite match in your question.
WITH data AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (4, NULL, 3)
        ,   (1, 4, 1)
        ,   (5, 4, 1)
        ,   (6, 4, 1)
        ,   (2, 1, 1)
        ,   (3, 1, 1)
        ,   (7, 3, 2)
        ,   (8, 3, 1)
    ) t (id,pid,weight)
)
, rec AS (
    SELECT  d.id, d.id AS parentID, d.weight
    FROM    data d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  r.id, d.id, d.weight
    FROM    data d
    INNER JOIN rec r
        ON  r.parentID = d.pid
    
    )
SELECT  id, SUM(weight)
FROM    rec
GROUP BY ID

For top iteration, we fetch all the IDs, and for the recursive part, the join is between the top ID and the current parentID.
Finally, one groups by the original ID to get the total weights.

yes, it works! Thanks a lot!

Great, feel free to approve the answer if it was helpful
