SQL Server recursion with multiple tables
I'm trying to get users that are part of groups, but groups can be members of groups as well. So the question is about who has "effective" access to certain groups. I've seen many examples of using CTE on SQL Server and this seems like the same case, but all the examples are pretty simple about a single table like an org chart. In my case, I have to join multiple tables and just can't grasp the whole recursion thing.
The tables are:
usergroup: what users have which groups
uid int
gid int
groupgroup: which groups give which groups
parentid int
childid int
group: many groups are in a single sourceid.
gid int
sourceid int
name varchar
For example:
usergroup

uid   gid
------------
1     101
1     102
2     102
2     120

groupgroup

parentid  childid
-------------------
103       101
110       103
120       110

group

gid   sourceid    name
-----------------------
101   5           group101
102   5           group102
103   5           group103
110   8           group110
120   8           group120

Where the difference between parentid and childid is that parentid GRANTS childid. So if you are a member of parentid , you have effective access to childid. As expected, parentid and childid WILL EXIST in the group table.
My goal is to simply get a list of all users that have access to which groups in a given source (sourceid). Without the nesting, it would be simple for sourceid of 5:
select *
from usergroup
inner join group on group.gid = usergroup.gid
where group.sourceid = 5

And this query would give me that user 1 has groups 101, 102, and user 2 has 102.
But the issue is that a user could have a parent gid that gives a childid via any level of nesting, and those childids can be a gid in the sourceid of 5.
I would instead hope to get that user 1 still has 101 and 102 directly, and that user 2 has 102 directly AND 101 and 103 because of nesting.
At a basic level, I just need to know users XYS have groups ABC in the source either directly OR via nesting and a flag or other marker if it's nesting vs direct. If we could get something like a level (0 = direct, 1 = one level up, etc...) that's all the better.
I can do this in Java code by making a big map/list and looping, but is there an elegant way to get it from SQL Server directly and perhaps faster than in code?
Thank you!

Please provide a [mre] with sample data (covering all edge cases) and desired results.

I don't see what differs this from any other recursive cte questions, there are a couple asked today which deals with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78866869/how-to-know-subtrees-knot-sum/78868155#78868155 just follow the parentGroupID etc

Hint: use the CTE examples you see everywhere on your groupgroup table, to produce a projection that returns a row for every descendant (as a childid) of every ancestor (as a parentid). Then replace usergroup in your query with that CTE.

A recursive CTE consists of an anchor query followed by a UNION ALL to one or more recursive queries.  (Typically, there is only one recursive part, but in some scenarios, such as binary trees, there may be more than one.)
For your case, the anchor will be a select of all of the direct group memberships from the UserGroup table. This part is just a normal query that seeds the reciursive CTE with an initial set of rows.
The recursive part of the query expands on the existing rows with an additional query (or queries) that joins the existing rows with whatever is needed to recursively expand the results. In your case, it will join the CTE with the GroupGroup table to walk the chain of and include any parent groups.
For each row in the seed set, the recursive query might return zero, one or many additional rows. These results are both added to the combined result set and fed back into the recursion, possibly yielding even more results. There must be a limit though. BY default, SQL Server allows 100 levels or recursion, but this can be overridden with the MAXRECURSION option.
with ExpandedUserGroups as (
    -- Anchor part
    select ug.uid, ug.gid
    from UserGroup ug

    union all

    -- Recursive part
    select xug.uid, gg.parentid
    from ExpandedUserGroups xug
    join GroupGroup gg
        on gg.childid = xug.gid
)
select xug.uid, xug.gid, g.sourceid, g.name
from ExpandedUserGroups xug
join [Group] g
    on g.gid = xug.gid
order by xug.uid, xug.gid;

Results



uid
gid
sourceid
name




1
101
5
group101


1
102
5
group102


1
103
5
group103


1
110
8
group110


1
120
8
group120


2
102
5
group102


2
120
8
group120



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

That's it, thank you. I modified the fiddle to switch parentid and childid, add a level, and a where clause. But this was the key, thank you!

Slight modification to the above switching parent and child, adding a level of nesting, and a where clause, but that union was the key.
with ExpandedUserGroups as (
    -- Anchor part
    select ug.uid, ug.gid, 0 as level
    from UserGroup ug
    union all
    -- Recursive part
    select xug.uid, gg.childid, level+1 as level
    from ExpandedUserGroups xug
    join GroupGroup gg
        on gg.parentid = xug.gid
)
select xug.uid, xug.gid, xug.level, g.sourceid
from ExpandedUserGroups xug
join [Group] g
    on g.gid = xug.gid
where sourceid = 5
order by xug.uid, xug.gid;




uid
gid
sourceid
name
level




1
101
5
group101
0


1
102
5
group102
0


2
101
5
group101
3


2
102
5
group102
0


2
103
5
group103
2



